# Get data from Parse Array into local CGFloat Array

Tags: swift, parse-platform

Im having trouble with Swift and Parse.com array because the documentation does not say much about the Syntax and im pretty new to Swift.

So what i want to do:

I want to add two values from two CGFloats to my Database.

Later i want to pull this two Values out from Parse Database and write them into a local CG Float array. But im Having a lot of trouble

Here is my Code for uploading the Value to the Parse.com Array: (This works fine, i have the three values in my Pase Database)

```
 var positionAx : CGFloat = -1000
 var positionAy : CGFloat = -1000



var post = PFObject(className: "Post")

        post["antwortA_koord"] = [positionAx, positionAy, 0]
        post.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{(success: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

       if success == false {

                self.displayAlert("Could not post your Question", error: "Please check your internet connection")
            }

       else {
              println("You have posted")
            }
```

And here the Code for Getting the data from Parse.com

```
var  buttonA = [CGFloat] ()

var query = PFQuery(className:"Post")

    query.whereKey("user", notEqualTo: PFUser.currentUser().username)
    query.limit = 1

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error == nil {


            for object in objects {

         self.buttonA.append(object["antwortA_koord"] as CGFloat)

         println(self.buttonA)


               }
```

I get an error in this line: self.buttonA.append(object["antwortA_koord"] as CGFloat) but i dont know how to write the Syntax in the right way.

I hope you can help me

Comment: Is buttonA declared in a function, or it's a property of the class?

Comment: If you do so, then you don't need the self before buttonA